# How to add new key to existing child of Firebse (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 poolonwheels-142415
    -KXLo2fvrZ48vBQV-Toc
         -msg: none
```

I need to add a new key with value `none` to the existing child -KXLo2fvrZ48vBQV-Toc of Firebase.

I need the code for the following in android

```
poolonwheels-142415
    -KXLo2fvrZ48vBQV-Toc
         msg: none
         name:none
         age:none
```

If possible give the complete code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add key and value to all childs in JSON tree in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834402/add-key-and-value-to-all-childs-in-json-tree-in-firebase)

Comment: This should be a fairly simple call to [`updateChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) with a `Map` containing the new `name` and `age` values. What have you already tried? Which part is giving you problems?

Comment: Im a newbie can you give me some sample code please @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The link I gave you has an example of how to call `updateChildren()` with a map. If you're having trouble making it work, show the code that you've tried.

Comment: Thank you!  It worked @Frank